# Visual Studio 2012 Workflow Pane Width

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, workflow-foundation

I am currently using the Workflow designer in Visual Studio 2012 to create an automated build workflow. The XAML document that I am using was not created by me and I am new to Workflow. Some of the titles of the panes are too long to display fully and I am unable to read the text of the title. This is a problem because I am following a document, created by another developer at my workplace, that references the titles.

I thought that increasing the 'zoom' would help, but the text also zooms and remains obscured. I have tried searching Google and SO for a way to widen the panes, but have not found a solution.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this task? I would also appreciate other suggestions.